# <f:selectItems is not returning value in <p:selectOneMenu>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, el

I have a problem with getting value of f:selectItems but it is returning its label. 
here is the code;

```
<p:selectOneMenu>.
    <p:outputLabel value="Major Diseases"></p:outputLabel>
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{dataMigeration.mdId}"> 
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems var="t" 
                   value="#{dataMigeration.majorDiseas}"
                   itemLabel="#{t.value.mdName}"
                   itemValue="#{t.value}"/>                             
    <p:ajax listener="#{dataMigeration.getSubDiseasesByMojarDisease(dataMigeration.mdId)}" 
            event="change"  update="dataMigration"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

here is the dataMigeration class

```
@ManagedBean(name="dataMigeration")
@SessionScoped
public class DataMigeration{
String mdId;
private List<SelectItem> majorDiseas = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
public List<SelectItem> getMajorDiseas() {
    majorDiseas = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();  
    System.out.println("DataMigeration.getMajorDiseas():");
    List<DiseaseCategory> majorDiseasesList = new ArrayList<DiseaseCategory>();     

    majorDiseasesList=DataManager.findAllRecords();

    for (DiseaseCategory obj : majorDiseasesList) {
        majorDiseas.add(new SelectItem(obj.getMdId(), obj.getMdName()));
    }

    return majorDiseas;
}

public void getSubDiseasesByMojarDisease(String mdId)
{
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n |  value:"+mdId);

}
```

but I am getting mdId=itemLabel of f:selectedItem but I want to get itemValue of f:selectem. SomeWhere I have done before but I forgot now how to get ItemValue.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'f:selectItems' statement is wrong.  You can use the 'var' attribute to loop through a list of complex Java objects to dynamically create a list of SelectItem objects.  (See http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-dropdown-box-example/ for examples)

But in this case, you've already created your list of SelectItem objects in the backing bean, so just reference it like this instead:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{dataMigeration.majorDiseas}" />
```